# NHibernate UPDATE doesn't work

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to update my records using NHibernate. Until now I only created SELECT statements. Now I need to do an update and I can't seem to make it work.

Here is a simplified function I'm calling.

```
    public void UpdateDataEditedInDrobneAwarieGrid()
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                    string query = "UPDATE [MESdb].[dbo].[LogIn] SET Uzytkownik='a..' WHERE ID=3";

                session.CreateSQLQuery(query);

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

NHibernateHelper:

```
 public class NHibernateHelper
{

    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {

                var NHibernateConfig = new Configuration();
                NHibernateConfig.Configure(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                @"~\Models\NHibernate\hibernate.cfg.xml"), "MESdb");
                NHibernateConfig.AddDirectory(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                @"~\Models\NHibernate\Mapping")));
                _sessionFactory = NHibernateConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong ?

The SQL statement is fine. Checked it in MSSQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute an **UPDATE** as a part of the `session.CreateSQLQuery(query);` we have to explicitly call `ExecuteUpdate()`;

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
  .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: Which is designed for bulk updates, but not for setting properties on persistent objects. Persistent objects should be retrieved and changed, then automatically updated on transaction.Commit()

Comment: @ErikHart This comment does not belong to the answer. It belongs to the question. And also it is not correct. for bulk updates, Erik, you should check the DML. The `CreateSQLQuery` is there for us, to get quick access to ADO.NET, while still managed by NHiberante. Simply, there are situations, when you cannot use the mapping. Trust me, you will face it sooner or later ;)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will work with objects instead of writing SQL, for example:

```
public void UpdateDataEditedInDrobneAwarieGrid()
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var login = session.Get<LogIn>(3);
        login.Uzytkownik = "a..";
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't even need to call session.SaveOrUpdate(login), if you only do an update (you only have to Save() new objects to attach them to the session). Many people wonder why NHibernate updates objects on DB, although never a SaveOrUpdate has been done. On the other hand, even with SaveOrUpdate/Save(), changes will not be sent immediately, but NHibernate tries to batch them and send them in a row, usually on Commit(). Congratulations, you're one step closer to correct NHibernate implementation and further away from common errors and anti-patterns!